# Determining the region bounded by these curves

Tags: calculus

I have a homework problem (in a Calc 2 course) that asks me to calculate the volume of the solid of revolution formed by rotating the following three curves around the y axis :

$y = 8 - x^2$, $y = x^2$, $x = 0$ .

Of course, the region bounded by the first two curves is bisected by the line $x=0$, so what region do I use for my calculation?

Comment: I think you should calculate the whole thing, which as you mention is just one of those halves multiplied by two...

Comment: Either (or both!) would give the same solid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since it is about y-axis, you need to rearrange the eq.

EDIT: This is the integral since the area is constant.

You need two integrals:

$$\pi \int^{4}_{0} (  \sqrt{y})^2 dy + \pi \int^{8}_{4} ( \sqrt{8-y})^2 dy $$

[image]

(old)
$$\pi \int^{8}_{0} (8-y-y)^2 dy$$

$$\pi \int^{8}_{0} (8-y+y)^2 dy = \pi \int^{8}_{0} (8)^2 dy  = \pi \left[ 64y \right]_0^{8}$$

Comment: Thaaaaaank you. Got it!